# How to send SIGSTOP to all processes that launched from a shell script

Tags: c, linux, shell

I have a shell script that launches 4 other binaries. I am sending SIGSTOP to the shell script. Does this stop all other 4 processes also? If not, what should I do to forward the SIGSTOP to these processes? Similar is the case with SIGCONT.

I have the C source code for all the 4 binaries.

Comment: I think SIGSTOP cannot be trapped.

Comment: Is the shell-script something you're running from the command-line, or running via `execvp`, etc. from a forked child process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call `setpgid()` in the forked child process that will execute the shell script. That will give any spawned processes from that shell script the same group ID as the child process.  You can then use `killpg()` to send a signal to the entire group that all processes in that group will receive.

For instance, if inside the child process you called `setpgid(0, 0)`, this would setup a special instance where the child-process' group ID will be set to the same value as the child's PID.  Then any processes overlaid on the child process using one of the `exec` family of functions will have the same group-ID value that the child had.  In addition, any processes that the newly overlaid process may spawn will also have the same group ID (i.e., your shell-script).  You can then, using `killpg()`, send a signal to any processes sharing a group ID value using just the child's PID value that `fork()` returned since the group ID of the child process is the same value as the child's PID after the `setpgid(0, 0)` call.

If you are using `fork()`, depending on how quickly you need to send signals to the group from the parent process may create some synchronization issues ... for example, you want to immediately send a signal to the process group right after forking the child process.  There are two work-arounds for this:  Either 1) use `vfork()` instead of fork, so that the parent is suspended until the child has changed it's group-ID and successfully called `exec`, or 2) call `setpgid()` in the parent process *as well as* in the child-process, but in the parent, rather than using `setgpid(0, 0)` like you would in the child, you can use `setpgid(CHILD_PID, CHILD_PID)`.  Then it won't matter which call was successful (one of them will be successful, and the other will fail with a `EACCES`), and any successive signals sent from the parent wil now go to a valid group ID.

Comment: Not an expert on group ID's, but couldn't there be other processes in the same group?

Comment: If you set the process group ID to the same value as the child's process ID using the special case `setpgid(0, 0)`, that chance is pretty remote.

Comment: Consider a process A launches a shell script B. The group id of process A is 'G'. The script B launches four other process C, D ,E , and F.   Does C, D E & F will have group id of 'G'?

Comment: Yes, they will if A launches shell-script B through an `exec` function.  Child processes inherit the group ID of their parent process.  So initially the child process group ID is the same as the parent.  If you didn't change the child's group ID through `setgpid`, then when you send your signal, the parent would also catch the signal, which would be bad.  So by changing the process group ID of the child and any processes the child spawns (or are overlaid on the child), you effectively isolate the parent from any signals you want to send to a group of processes spawned off of a child process.

Answer (score 1):

If your processes form a group, you can use standard `kill`(1). `man kill` has the following info:

```
pid... 
    Specify the list of processes that kill should signal. Each pid can be one of five things: 
n 
    where n is larger than 0. The process with pid n will be signaled. 
    All processes in the current process group are signaled.
-1 
    All processes with pid larger than 1 will be signaled. 
-n 
     where n is larger than 1. All processes in process group n are signaled. When an argument of the form '-n' is given, and it is meant to denote a process group, either the signal must be specified first, or the argument must be preceded by a '--' option, otherwise it will be taken as the signal to send. 
commandname
```

It seems to me that the '-n' specification might help you

```
kill -STOP -- "-$(pgrep myparentproc)"
```

Comment: I don't see how this is a substitute for the functions @Jason mentioned, since you first have to get the processes into a process group, which is what the bulk of his answer describes.  This only replaces the `killpg` call.

Comment: @Ben - exactly what I meant. Sorry if I could have made it clearer. I'm in the habit posting minimal samples, and sometime adding just a few dense lines seems to add more confusion than it solves...